# Issue on build {fmt} with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, fmt

I have a issue on build {fmt} with CMake.

The structure of a project is the following:

```sh
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── dep
│   └── fmt
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── main.cpp
```

`./CMakeLists.txt` is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(fmtdemo)
add_subdirectory(dep/fmt)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

`./src/CMakeLists.txt` is the following:

```
project(fmtdemo)
add_library(fmtdemo main.cpp)
add_library(fmtdemo::fmtdemo ALIAS fmtdemo)
target_link_libraries(fmtdemo PUBLIC fmt::fmt-header-only)
add_executable(fdemo main.cpp)
```

`./src/main.cpp` is the following:

```cpp
#include "../dep/fmt/include/fmt/core.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fmt::print("Elapsed time: {0:.2f} seconds", 1.23);
    string message = fmt::format("The answer is {}", 42);
    return 0;
}
```

When I build it I receive an error:

```sh
CMakeFiles/fdemo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `void fmt::v5::print<char [30], double, 0>(char const (&) [30], double&&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3fmt2v55printIA30_cJdELi0EEEvRKT_DpOT0_[_ZN3fmt2v55printIA30_cJdELi0EEEvRKT_DpOT0_]+0x78): undefined reference to `fmt::v5::vprint(fmt::v5::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v5::format_args)'
CMakeFiles/fdemo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > fmt::v5::format<char [17], int, char>(char const (&) [17], int&&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3fmt2v56formatIA17_cJiEcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT1_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EEERKT_DpOT0_[_ZN3fmt2v56formatIA17_cJiEcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT1_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EEERKT_DpOT0_]+0x7f): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
fmt::v5::internal::vformat<char>(fmt::v5::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v5::basic_format_args<fmt::v5::basic_format_context<std::back_insert_iterator<fmt::v5::internal::buffer<char> >, char> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/CMakeFiles/fdemo.dir/build.make:83: recipe for target 'src/fdemo' failed
make[2]: *** [src/fdemo] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:170: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/fdemo.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/fdemo.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: `fdemo` executable is not linked with `fmt`. I think you want to link `fdemo` not `fmtdemo`, with `fmt`

Comment: @KamilCuk Can you tell me how to link the `fdemo` executable with `fmt`? I am not familiar with CMake  Thank you!
U can edit the files on https://github.com/ChungZH/FmtPost

Comment: You did `target_link_libraries(fmtdemo PUBLIC fmt::fmt-header-only)` . What you want is `target_link_libraries(fdemo PUBLIC fmt::fmt-header-only)` I guess.

Comment: `CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:6 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "fdemo" which is not built by this
  project.`
@KamilCuk After the modification, the error became like this.

Comment: `add_executable(fdemo main.cpp)` - `fdemo` is clearly build by your cmake. You should add it *after* add_executable, not before.

Answer (score 4):

You should link with `fmt`, not `fmt-header-only`:

```
target_link_libraries(fmtdemo PUBLIC fmt::fmt)
```

Or if you want to use the header-only configuration, make sure to include the `fmt/format.h` header instead of `fmt/core.h`. The latter provides a subset of the API for faster compilation and requires linking with the `fmt` library.

Comment: error: `CMakeFiles/fdemo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function void 'fmt::v5::print<char [30], double, 0>(char const (&) [30], double&&)':`